# SyntaxError: Unexpected token else in nodejs

Tags: node.js

i am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token else in nodejs app in line 92 col7

in app.js

```
var express = require('express'), everyauth = require('everyauth');

everyauth.debug = true;

var usersByLogin = {
  'krishna': {
    login: 'krishna',
    email: 'krishna@blogab.com',
    password: 'krishna'
  }
};

everyauth
  .password
  //.loginWith('email')
  .loginWith('login')
  .getLoginPath('/login')
  .postLoginPath('/login')
  .loginView('bcore/login.jade')
  .loginLocals( function (req, res, done) {
    setTimeout( function () {
      done(null, {
        title: 'blogab - login'
      });
    }, 200);
  })
  .authenticate( function (login, password) {
    var errors = [];
    if (!login) errors.push('Missing login');
    if (!password) errors.push('Missing password');
    if (errors.length) return errors;
    var user = usersByLogin[login];
    if (!user) return ['Login failed'];
    if (user.password !== password) return ['Login failed'];
    return user;
  })
  .getRegisterPath('/register')
  .postRegisterPath('/register')
  .registerView('bcore/register.jade')
  .registerLocals( function (req, res, done) {
    setTimeout( function () {
      done(null, {
        title: ' Register'
      });
    }, 200);
  })
  .extractExtraRegistrationParams( function (req) {
    return {
      email: req.body.email
    };
  })
  .validateRegistration( function (newUserAttrs, errors) {
    var login = newUserAttrs.login;
    if (usersByLogin[login]) errors.push('Login already taken');
    return errors;
  })
  .registerUser( function (newUserAttrs) {
    var login = newUserAttrs[this.loginKey()];
    return usersByLogin[login] = newUserAttrs;
  })

  .loginSuccessRedirect('/admin/')
  .registerSuccessRedirect('/admin/');

var app = express.createServer(
  express.bodyParser(),
  express.static(__dirname + "/public"),
  express.cookieParser(),
  express.session({ secret: 'htuayreve'}),
  everyauth.middleware()
);

app.configure( function () {
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('templates/default/index', {
    title: 'blogab',
    users: JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)
  });                           
});

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  res.render('bcore/login', {
    title: 'login',
    users: JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)
  });
});

app.get('/admin/newpost', function (req, res) {
  res.render('bcore/newpost', {
    title: 'Blogab-newpost',
    users: ';
    JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)
  });
});

app.get('/admin/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('bcore/admin', {
    title: 'core',
    users: JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)
  });
});

everyauth.helpExpress(app);

app.listen(1224, function(){
  console.log("blogab is  running on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port,  app.settings.env);
});
```

i don't know what i am doing wrong i use everyauth before when redirection url was \  it was working perfectly but when i changed it is not working properly

Comment: The whole code you pasted does not have the keyword `else` once in it. Are you sure you pasted the right code?

Comment: Please indent your code sensibly, it makes it much easier to debug. I don't know if it's strictly a syntax error, but `return usersByLogin[login] = newUserAttrs;` certainly *looks* horrible, may not work as you want it to - it should be broken into two statements. You also have a stray `';` in your third `app.get()` which is a big syntax error.

Comment: i pasted every bit of code thats in app.js

Answer (score 1):

check out line 94... this bit

```
app.get('/admin/newpost', function (req, res) {
  res.render('bcore/newpost', {
    title: 'Blogab-newpost',
    users: ';
    JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)
  });
});
```

this bit

```
users: ';
```

should be

```
user : ''
```

it probably thinks its an inline if/else

Answer (score 0):

try checking for missed typed syntax, and if there are nothing wrong with the main file try checking the other file.

note: if you are trying to use else after ifs don't forget to move " **;** " from the ifs to the last else.

```
if (...) {...};         
//            ^ move this
if (...) {...}          
else if (...) {...}     
else {...};             
//        ^to here, this happens to the best of us that uses ;
```

if you don't move the " **;** ", it's the same thing as typing else without ifs,and because there is no ifs it wont expect else if or else right after.

and also if you don't want to deal with these kind of thing just remove the " **;** " sign  all together, but... if you really need to use it just remove it from the ifs...